# How can I seperate view of stocks like in stocks and then out of stocks

Tags: javascript, php

I have a project in which I have to show in stocks and out of stocks so I get data from DB with manual CI pagination.But what happens is out of stocks can in between any where so I want to show at the end only what can I do except sorting it.

This is my model
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('image');

```
  if($orderby == 0){
     $this->db->order_by('sort', 'desc');
  }
  if($orderby == 1){
     $this->db->order_by('price', 'asc');
  }
  if($orderby == 2){
      $this->db->order_by('price', 'desc');
     // $this->db->order_by('price desc ,stocks desc ');

  }
  if($orderby == 3){
     $this->db->order_by('title', 'asc');
  }
  if($orderby == 4){
     $this->db->order_by('brand', 'asc');
  }
  if($orderby == 5){
     $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
  }
  if($orderby == 6){
     $this->db->order_by('id', 'asc');
  }
  if($orderby == 7){
     $this->db->order_by('stocks', 'desc');
  }

  $this->db->limit($limit, $offset); 
  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Why do you not want to sort your data first? If you don't, then you will have to loop over it twice - and in the first loop, output all items that have "in stock" status, and in the second one, the others.

Comment: Thats is my task I have to seperate in stocks and out of stocks by showing in stocks first then out of stocks

Comment: Well then do it, what is holding you back ...?

Comment: how to do that is the problem :->

Comment: Did I not already said _how_ in the very first comment?